# How to access a java class variable value (dynamic) from one class to another class?

Tags: java, selenium

My requirement is, I wanted to read some data in one page and verify that data with another page data, to make sure that both data's present in two different pages are the same.
I'm using selenium and Java

Note: All the data's I'm reading at run time from the UI.

```
Class User{

String userText;

public User(){}

public void getUserName(){

// Here i'm reading the text from the user page
userText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath")).getText();
}

}

Class Admin{

public adminText;

// Here i'm reading the text from the admin page

public void getAdminUserName(){
adminText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath")).getText();
}

// Now I wanted to use, User class variable value userText in the admin class. So that I can assert both the data's (User and Admin).

User obj = new User();

assertEquals(obj.userText, adminText); // Asertion failed.

}
}
```

But If I create an object for User class, the userText variable is assigned to null. So my assertion is getting failed.

Can anyone please let me know, how I can I access the value of one class to another class?
I know we can use static, but I felt that is a bad practice to do that here.

Comment: either initialize User#userText in the constructor, or change the method signature of User#getUserName to return a String and invoke that in the comparison.  you will also have to apply that same fix to your Admin class.

Comment: I cannot use constructor here, Because from the admin page, if i create an object for User class,it will try to find an element. And it will fail. And throw an null pointer exception. Because i cannot find an element from admin page to the user page

Comment: Even i can't able to use the getUserName method to return a string. As i told, i cannot find an element from the admin page to the user page

Answer (score 0):

You weren't calling the methods, creating the admin object, or defining adminText as String.

```
Class User{

String userText;

public User(){}

public void getUserName(){

// Here i'm reading the text from the user page
userText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath")).getText();
}

}

Class Admin{

String adminText;

// Here i'm reading the text from the admin page

public void getAdminUserName(){
adminText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath")).getText();
}

// Now I wanted to use, User class variable value userText in the admin class. So that I can assert both the data's (User and Admin).



}

User obj = new User();
obj.getUserName();

Admin adminObj = new Admin();
adminObj.getAdminUserName();

assertEquals(obj.userText, adminObj.adminText); // Asertion failed.
```

Not a complete answer, because you'd still need to navigate to the other page. driver.get(page_1), driver.get(page_2)

Comment: Yes.. You are right. I need to navigate to the page 1. But in my case I can't able to move backward

Comment: Can we make User class as singleton. So that object will be initialised only once. I haven't tried this... But thinking whether it works

Comment: User obj = new User();  driver.get(page1);
obj.getUserName();

Admin adminObj = new Admin(); driver.get(page2);
adminObj.getAdminUserName();

Comment: If I call obj.getUserName() from my admin class, it won't work. Because I need to navigate to the User page. But I can't navigate back to the user page when I'm in the admin page

Comment: ah, ok... I've updated.  You just need those calls outside of the admin class.

Comment: you probably want some functions for navigation too...  you may want to reconsider the whole structure of this.